# Add dependence of the project into my custom gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm new in the Gradle world and I'm writing a personal plugin for executing the operation on the database, an example:
create a database, delete the database, create a table e insert a value into database, but I have a problem with import dependence for the project that uses my plugin, an example for creating a database using a JDBC I have to need the driver JDBC for the database, this driver is content into project main.

My question is: How getting a dependency jar for the database into my Gradle plugin?

This is my code

```
package io.vincentpalazzo.gradledatabase.task;

import io.vincentpalazzo.gradledatabase.exstension.GradleDatabaseExstension;
import io.vincentpalazzo.gradledatabase.persistence.DataSurce;
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * @author https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo
 */
public class CreateDatabaseTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    public void createAction() {

        GradleDatabaseExstension project = getProject().getExtensions().findByType(GradleDatabaseExstension.class);

        String url = project.getUrl();
        String driverClass = project.getDriver(); //The drive name database is different
        String username = project.getUsername();
        String password = project.getPassword();
        String nameDatabase = project.getNameDatabase();
        String nameJar = project.getNameJar();

        if (findDependecyFileJarForDriver(nameJar)) {
            System.out.println("Jar findend");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Jar not found");
        }

        DataSurce dataSource = new DataSurce();
        if (dataSource.connectionDatabase(driverClass, url, username, password)) {
            if (dataSource.createDatabese(nameDatabase)) {
                System.out.println("Database " + nameDatabase + " created");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean findDependecyFileJarForDriver(String nameJar) {
        if (nameJar == null || nameJar.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input parameter is null");
        }

        Iterator<Configuration> iterable = getProject().getConfigurations().iterator();
        boolean finded = false;

        while ((!finded) || (iterable.hasNext())) {
            Configuration configuration = iterable.next();
            Set<File> filesSet = configuration.resolve();
            for (File file : filesSet) {
                String nameFile = file.getName();
                if (nameFile.contains(nameJar)) {
                    //Now?;
                    finded = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return finded;
    }
}
```

And this is [my project](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/gradle-database) and this is the referend for [my post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/add-dependence-of-the-project-into-my-custom-plugin/31697) on Gradle forum

Sorry for my terrible English but I'm learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to add the answer to this post.

The better solution I found is using this [plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.lingocoder.jarexec)

I used the plugin inside the my code, this is an example

```
public abstract class AbstractTaskGradleDatabase extends DefaultTask {

    protected JarHelper jarHelper;
    protected Optional<File> jar;

    protected void init(){

        jarHelper = new JarHelper(getProject());
        jar = jarHelper.fetch("nameDependence");
    }
}
```

inside the builld.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation gradleApi()

    implementation 'com.lingocoder:jarexec.plugin:0.3'

}
```

ps: the answer can be changed in the time because the version of the plugin is an beta